# Symfony2 routing from POST

Tags: symfony, post, routes

I'm issuing a POST body of: `controller=user&action=add`
To the URL: `my_site.com/`
I want acoording to post run  `addAction` from `UserController`

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function addAction()
    {
        //return $this->redirectToRoute('test');
        return $this->render('BeerwerdClaberonBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a route and with that route you can specify a request method.
For example:

```
/**
 * @Route("/contact")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
```

For more info see the documentation on routing:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-http-method-requirements